iOS 18 drag gesture blocks scrollview
I have a basic subview that is nested inside a vertical scrollview, this subview has a drag gesture applied to it that should allow it to drag left and right. This works just fine on iOS 15-17 and does NOT block the scroll view, however on iOS 18 this drag gesture prevents scrolling (I cannot scroll the view by dragging on the subview) I can only move the scrollview outside of the frame of this subview.
I tried a normal .gesture a .simultaneousGesture and a highprioritygesture, all had the same issue. There's a ton of people with the same issue on this Apple Thread. Is there a fix that supports iOS 17 and iOS 18?
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FullSwipeNavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                MessageView().enableFullSwipePop(true)
            } label: {
                Text("Message view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MessageView: View {
    @State private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                // Swipable view
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
                    HStack {
                        Button { } label: { Text("show Image") }
                        Button { } label: { Text("show Video") }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 150).offset(x: dragOffset.width)
                .highPriorityGesture (
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            if value.translation.width > 0 { // Drag the message right to reply to it
                                dragOffset = value.translation
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            withAnimation {
                                dragOffset = .zero
                            }
                        })
                )
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity) {
                    // Nothing here
                } onPressingChanged: { starting in
                    if starting {
                        // Show custom context menu in 1 second if still holding
                    }
                }
                
                // Other rectangles
                ForEach(1..<10) { index in
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(Text("Rectangle \(index + 1)").foregroundColor(.white).font(.headline))
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}


// IGNORE everything below this, unless you want to see how full swipe pop works

struct FullSwipeNavigationStack<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    @State private var customGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.name = UUID().uuidString
        gesture.isEnabled = false
        return gesture
    }()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            content
                .background {
                    AttachGestureView(gesture: $customGesture)
                }
        }
        .environment(\.popGestureID, customGesture.name)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .init(customGesture.name ?? "")), perform: { info in
            if let userInfo = info.userInfo, let status = userInfo["status"] as? Bool {
                customGesture.isEnabled = status
            }
        })
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func enableFullSwipePop(_ isEnabled: Bool) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(FullSwipeModifier(isEnabled: isEnabled))
    }
}

fileprivate struct PopNotificationID: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: String?
}

fileprivate extension EnvironmentValues {
    var popGestureID: String? {
        get {
            self[PopNotificationID.self]
        }
        
        set {
            self[PopNotificationID.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct FullSwipeModifier: ViewModifier {
    var isEnabled: Bool
    @Environment(\.popGestureID) private var gestureID
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *){
            content
               .onChange(of: isEnabled, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in
                   guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                       "status": newValue
                   ])
               }
               .onAppear {
                   guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                       "status": isEnabled
                   ])
               }
               .onDisappear(perform: {
                   guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                       "status": false
                   ])
               })
        } else {
            content
                .onAppear {
                    guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                        "status": isEnabled
                    ])
                }
                .onChange(of: isEnabled) { newValue in
                    guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                        "status": newValue
                    ])
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                        "status": false
                    ])
                }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct AttachGestureView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            if let parentViewController = uiView.parentViewController {
                if let navigationController = parentViewController.navigationController {
                    if let _ = navigationController.view.gestureRecognizers?.first(where: { $0.name == gesture.name }) {
                        print("Already Attached")
                    } else {
                        navigationController.addFullSwipeGesture(gesture)
                        print("Attached")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension UINavigationController {
    func addFullSwipeGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureSelector = interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.value(forKey: "targets") else { return }
        
        gesture.setValue(gestureSelector, forKey: "targets")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}

fileprivate extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        sequence(first: self) {
            $0.next
        }.first(where: { $0 is UIViewController}) as? UIViewController
    }
}


It is not clear what the expected result is here. Which is the part of the code that would "allow it to drag left and right"? As it is, the gesture allows the blue rectangle to be dragged in any direction, not just horizontally.

@AndreiG. this should be addressed now. Thanks.

I wrote an extensive answer on this topic, it may be useful to read.
Although my answer mentioned using a .simultaneousGesture and a .highPriorityGesture, after some more testing, I think using just a .highPriorityGesture may suffice:
.highPriorityGesture(
    TapGesture() // <- required
        .onEnded {
            //Tap action
            print("tap triggered") // <- regular tap moves here
        }
        .exclusively(before: swipeGesture) // <- required
)

Here's the full code to try:
import SwiftUI

struct DragGestureScrollView: View {
    
    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //Define the drag gesture
        let swipeGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .updating($dragOffset) { gesture, offset, transaction in
                if abs(gesture.translation.width) > abs(gesture.translation.height) {
                    offset = gesture.translation
                }
            }
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                // First rectangle with drag gesture
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .overlay(
                        Text("Draggable rectangle")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.headline)
                    )
                    .offset(x: dragOffset.width)
                    .highPriorityGesture(
                        TapGesture() // <- required
                            .onEnded {
                                //Tap action
                                print("tap triggered") // <- regular tap moves here
                            }
                            .exclusively(before: swipeGesture) // <- required
                    )
                
                // Other rectangles
                ForEach(1..<10) { index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("Rectangle \(index + 1)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.headline)
                        )
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DragGestureScrollView()
}

Notes:

If your gesture always resets the offsets when the gesture ends, you can use .updating with a @GestureState which automatically resets itself on gesture end. The code above uses this method for setting/resetting dragOffset.

The drag gesture is defined separately, for convenience, but it could be part of the .highPriorityGesture.

Although not shown in your original code, if your Rectangle was the label of a Button, you'd have to move the button logic/actions inside the TapGesture action, or it will otherwise be ignored due to the .highPriorityGesture.


UPDATE 1:
Here's another example with a slightly different approach, for when the Rectangle may contain buttons and a context menu:
import SwiftUI

struct DragGestureScrollView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                // First rectangle with drag gesture
                DragRowButtonView()
                
                // Other rectangles
                ForEach(1..<10) { index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("Rectangle \(index + 1)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.headline)
                        )
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct DragRowButtonView: View {
    
    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let swipeGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .updating($dragOffset) { gesture, offset, transaction in
                if abs(gesture.translation.width) > abs(gesture.translation.height) {
                    offset = gesture.translation
                }
            }
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.blue
            
            HStack {
                Button {
                    print("Button 1 tapped")
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 1")
                }
                
                Button {
                    print("Button 2 tapped")
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 2")
                }
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .tint(.white)
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Text("*Long press for context menu")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                .padding()
        }
        .frame(height: 150)
        .contextMenu {
            Button {
                print("Context button tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Context Button")
            }
        }
        .offset(x: dragOffset.width)
        .gesture(
            TapGesture()
                .exclusively(before: swipeGesture)
        )
        .simultaneousGesture(swipeGesture, including: .none)
    }
}

#Preview {
    DragGestureScrollView()
}


UPDATE 2:
After much testing, it turns out that maybe simply adding a minimumDistance = 20 parameter to the DragGesture() may be enough (tested in Xcode Previews with iOS 18.1 simulator).
In my previous tests, I had inconsistent results with this method. But I am curious what others are getting based on the code below.
This version is based on the OP's code update that includes a more complete use case.
@Ahmed, note I switched to a simple NavigationStack, which gives you by default a swipe-back gesture (when swiping from the left edge of the screen).
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeGestureHomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                SwipeGestureListView()
            } label: {
                Text("Go to Messages")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwipeGestureListView: View {
    
    @State private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var isScrolling = false
    @State private var isSwiping = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                
                // Swipable view
                SwipeGestureMessageView()
                    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1) {
                        print("Should show context menu")
                    } onPressingChanged: { starting in
                        if starting {
                            // Show custom context menu in 1 second if still holding
                        }
                    }
                
                // Other rectangles
                ForEach(1..<10) { index in
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame(height: 150)
                        .overlay(Text("Rectangle \(index + 1)").foregroundColor(.white).font(.headline))
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct SwipeGestureMessageView: View {
    
    @State private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //
        let swipeGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20)
            .onChanged({ value in
                if value.translation.width > 0 { // Drag the message right to reply to it
                    dragOffset = value.translation
                }
            })
            .onEnded({ value in
                withAnimation {
                    dragOffset = .zero
                }
            })
        
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
            
            HStack {
                Button("Show Image") {
                    print("Show Image action")
                }
                
                Button("Show Video") {
                    print("Show Video action")
                }
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .tint(.white)
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Text("*Long press for context menu (console)")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                .padding()
        }
        .offset(x: dragOffset.width)
        .highPriorityGesture(swipeGesture)
        .frame(height: 150)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwipeGestureHomeView()
}


Thanks this kind of works but the problem is that my "rectangle" has multiple buttons on it, and I want to also handle long press gestures (for context menus), also this doesn't work if the overall view has a swipe to pop on it for navigation stacks. My use case is a basic message bubble. The user should be able to long press on the message to see a context menu, the user should be able to perform a left to right swipe on the whole screen to pop the view, and the user should be able to click on different portions of the message (image/text) to do something, and swipe on the message to reply.

I understand. It would be helpful if your example code included some of these features so that we can properly test any potential solutions. At least the rectangle buttons and the context menu. Can you maybe keep the already provided code as is and then add a version that included the above?

@AhmedZaidan I updated my answer with another example that allows tapping on buttons inside the rectangle.

Thank you so much for your time. I updated my code with my exact use case, sorry I didn't do this at the start. The code in my question worked 100 percent in < iOS 18. Just trying to get back this functionality. The full swipe pop is a custom modifier that allows the user to drag anywhere on the screen (not only the leading edge) to pop the view. Your updated code seems good but I have a custom context menu that is triggered with the onLongPress. Also having the full swipe pop blocks the high priority gesture.

@AhmedZaidan Thanks, I'll take a look. Is there a reason for the custom full swipe pop? Why not just use the default swipe to go back of NavigationStack?

I definitely could just use the default, a full swipe pop would be nicer though for a messaging app.

@AhmedZaidan See the new code in Update 2 of my answer.

Thank you so much!! Hopefully apple fixes this bug and I can use the full swipe pop again, I'll just take it off for now.

@AhmedZaidan Hopefully. You can try using the full swipe with the last code, I haven't tried. It might work, but not sure.
